# How can I make sure that there is no data in remote database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to use one of Firebase Database features - Transaction. For simplicity let's say that I want to update records if exists or create new one if it doesn't exist.

Code would look like this:

```
ref.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                if (mutableData.getValue() == null) {
                     // create new data
                } else {
                     // update new data
                }
                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean committed,
                               DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }
});
```

But there is one problem found in Firebase docs:

> Because doTransaction() is called multiple times, it must be able to handle null data. Even if there is existing data in your remote database, it may not be locally cached when the transaction function is run, resulting in null for the initial value.

So one time I get mutableData.getValue() as null and then I should create new data, but in reality it is null, because Firebase didn't cache it yet.

How can I differ these two situations?

Comment: As you've found, the `MutableData` may not correctly reflect the state of the data on the server. This is a normal part of how Firebase transactions work. The client will simply re-invoke your handler again with the actual value (or repeatedly if there are contending updates). You could use a `ValueEventListener` to detect *if* a value exists, but in general I'd recommend against it since you'd be nesting listeners and complicating code. In general it's best to accept that your transaction handler may be invoked multiple times and return the updated/created data on each invocation.

Comment: "and return the updated/created data on each invocation" - That's what I wanted to read ;)